# Counting numbers of possible password

Tags: combinatorics

Assume a computer password consists of 8 to 10 letters and/or digits. (Remember, a lower-case letter is different from the corresponding upper-case one.)

How many different passwords are possible if a password must include at least one uppercase letter, one lower-case letter, and one digit?

Comment: How many letters are allowed? The english alphabet?

Comment: Are you familiar with the method of Inclusion-Exclusion?

Comment: English alphabet,

Comment: And Yeah I think I'm familiar with Inclusion-exclusion

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, we need to do separate counts for length  $8$, $9$, and $10$, and add. But the calculations are very similar. We do the case length $9$.

There are $62$ symbols that can be used. It seems that repetitions are allowed, so there are $62^9$ strings of length $9$.

But some of these strings are not valid. There are $52^9$ "bad" strings with no digit, $36^9$  with no lower-case letters, and $36^{9}$ with no upper-case letters.

However, if we find the sum $52^9+36^9 +36^9$, we will be "double counting" the all digits strings, also double-counting the all lower-case strings, also double-counting the all upper-case strings. There are respectively $19^9$, $26^9$, and $26^9$ of these. Thus we end up with a total of
$$62^9 -52^9-36^9-36^9+10^9+26^9+26^9$$
valid passwords of length $9$.

Comment: i think it should be "double counting" the all digits strings, also double-counting the all lower-case strings, also double-counting the all upper-case strings. There are respectively 2*(10^9), 2*(26^9), and  2*(26^9)

Comment: Then 
valid passwords of length 9 should be: 62^9−52^9−36^9−36^9+2(10^9)+2(26^9)+2(26^9)